# check multiple List<int> for the same set of numbers -C#

Tags: c#

I have a Dictionary of customers with the list of books they have read.
ex :

```
c1 --> 1,2,3,6
c2 --> 3,5
c3 --> 1,2,3,4
```

I need to get a set of three books that are read in a row by most number of the customers ?
output should be like 1,2,3 .(these set of books are read by c1 and c3)
How should I proceed to figure out the sequence?

Comment: You could break the lists into all possible 3 item sequences and create a dictionary from it. e.g. for c1 -> [1,2,3], [2,3,6] etc. and then keep track of how many instances of each item exist (i.e. track count across all lists, ignoring duplicates in same list.)

Alternatively, you can convert arrays into strings and apply Knuth–Morris–Pratt

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
public static IDictionary<int, int> TopThreeMostReadBooksWithCount(Dictionary<string, List<int>> readBooks)
{
    //define dictionary to hold Books-Read count
    var booksReadCount = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    foreach(var readBookKvp in readBooks)
    {
        var booksReadByCustomer = readBookKvp.Value;

        foreach(var book in booksReadByCustomer)
        {
            booksReadCount[book] = booksReadCount.ContainsKey(book)
                                     ? booksReadCount[book] + 1 
                                     : 1;
         }
      }

       var topThreeMostReadBooksWithCount = booksReadCount.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)
                                      .Take(3)
                                      .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

          return topThreeMostReadBooksWithCount;
    }

   public static IList<int> TopThreeMostReadBooks(Dictionary<string, List<int>> readBooks)
   {
            //define dictionary to hold Books-Read count
            var booksReadCount = new Dictionary<int, int>();

            foreach (var readBookKvp in readBooks)
            {
                var booksReadByCustomer = readBookKvp.Value;

                foreach (var book in booksReadByCustomer)
                {
                    booksReadCount[book] = booksReadCount.ContainsKey(book)
                                           ? booksReadCount[book] + 1
                                           : 1;
                }
            }

            var topThreeMostReadBooks = booksReadCount.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)
                                        .Take(3)
                                        .Select(x => x.Key)
                                        .ToList();

            return topThreeMostReadBooks;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //c1-- > 1,2,3,6
            //c2-- > 3,5
            //c3-- > 1,2,3,4

            var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<int>> {
                { "c1",  new List<int>{1,2,3,6 } },
                { "c2",  new List<int>{ 3, 5 } },
                { "c3",  new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4 } }
            };

            var top3MostReadBooksWithCount = TopThreeMostReadBooksWithCount(dict);


            var justTop3MostReadBooks = TopThreeMostReadBooks(dict);
        }
```

And here is the output:

[image]